# Use absolute full path to the img instead of the local path

Tags: javascript

I use this snippet in my JavaScript code for preloading images:

```
my_path = "images/myimage.jpg";
my_image.src = my_path;
```

In this case, I have to use local path to the image as a value of my_path variable. If I use full path, I get error on the console, because the browser tries to load something like this:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/http://www.mysebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg`

How can I modify the snippet to be able to use absolute path to the image in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my_path = "/images/myimage.jpg";
```

See [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path) to understand the function of the forward slash in this context.

Comment: WOW! So simply adding forward slash roots the path?! I never realized that! Thanks, @James!