# How do I tell HTML a path to find an image?

Tags: html, image

If my HTML file is saved in a separate folder to the one with all my images in, how do I write a path to get the image?

For example, I write (i have tried both)

```
<img class="float" src="../CSS/images/web.jpg" alt="web developer directory">

<img class="float" src="/CSS/images/web.jpg" alt="web developer directory">
```

however this does not then display the image when I view the page.

I appreciate this may seem like a trivial question, however my knowledge is limited and I cannot find the solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Short of writing [a complete tutorial on how relative URLs work](http://www.htmlhelp.com/faq/html/basics.html#relative-url), this question is unanswerable without knowing the URL of the HTML document and the URL of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set either relative or absolute path.
Example of relative path is:

```
/CSS/images/web.jpg
```

and absolute path would be something like:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/CSS/images/web.jpg
```

Your example seems to be ok.
Be sure to check if your path is correct (are your images really inside CSS folder?). Also check if your picture extension is correct (.jpg or .jpeg).

About img tag and examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seemed all I needed to do was take off the very first /, any reason why that is?

Comment: Well check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your the folder path correctly

src="../CSS/images/web.jpg" alt="web developer directory"