# jquery mobile sound.play() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, audio

I have a Samsung S4 phone with Chrome browser 35.0.1916 with javaScript version 3.25.28.18, and Internet explorer.

I have a web app with jquery-1.7.1.js and jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/
In that app I have

```
var snd = new Audio("../assets/images/beep-xx.wav");
snd.play();
alert( "playing?");
```

But it makes no sound.

I've created a test page and on it both links work fine on both browsers on the phone.
Howere, on the phone in the webapp, these 3 lines produce no sound, even though alert is fired off.
Any Ideas on how to troubleshoot/debug?

A test page can be found here: http://pastebin.com/KDU8hZbZ

### edit1 addition:

more information - I've created a small html file that reproduces a problem - 
http://pastebin.com/4kCumsVz
It works on a desktop i.e. beeps on page load and link click, but on a cell phone - only when I press on the link.

Comment: is there a reason you are going back a directory (../)?

Comment: because this file is in webapp directory under the root.

Comment: if the directory is in a root folder try (/) without the dots and see if it helps..  --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path

Comment: But the test page/file in the same directory with the same link works fine.

Comment: ok. so the problem is some were else.