# Adding leading slash in urls

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I'm noticing some code such as

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    redirect url('/home');
}
```

The leading slash in /home doesn't seem to be necessary.  `url('home')` would still work.  What's the best practice?

Comment: Pick one and do it for whole project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its good practice to use `/` at string of redirect url.

Let's say you are browsing at `domain.com/some-url/` and if you use `redirect("home")` it will redirect you to `domain.com/some-url/home`. But if you use `redirect('/home')` it will redirect you to `domain.com/home`.

> Path starting with slash ensures that, the path is absolute to the
>   root directory and not the current directory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path) for more details.