# Localhost setting for multiple projects broken links

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I am running wamp on my pc, with more than one project, so in order to go to my project I need to go to `localhost/project1` and it works fine however href links (`/mypage.html`) keep pointing to `localhost/mypage.html`.

What do I need to change in order to keep the links in my project path?

Comment: You can use href links like (mypage.html) or (./mypage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is always better to create different **virtual hosts** Please refer this link to do the same https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

**OR**

use href links as (mypage.html) or (./mypage.html) which will add mypage.html to your last trailing "/" in url

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute link in the form of `href="/project1/mypage.html"` or use a relative link of the form `href="mypage.html"` or `href="./mypage.html"`.

A link with a leading slash is usually interpreted as an absolute link, beginning from the server's root.
In contrast, omitting the slash links relatively. A leading dot with a slash makes this even more explicit, saying "relative to the current path".

See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I can't link to my project this is a dev site , and the production site does not have constant name. Can I make my project my home page from the Apache setting?