# No image appears when using content: url() for a local image, but it will appear for a web url. Why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to turn this image into a button. It works when grabbing an image via website URL (**not my website**), but it won't work when using a relative path. The image simply won't appear.

Example:

```
.my-class {
     content: url(http://themedemo.wpeka.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png);
}
```

will work, but the following example with the url being a file path with the same downloaded image from the url above:

```
.my_class {
     content: url(/img/color.png);
}
```

Omitting or using quotes didn't result in any success.

My folders look like: 
-CSS->styles->general->style.css
-color.png

So, for testing purposes, I put color.png and the CSS folder within the same level of the project.

I got it work when trying:

```
contents: url(../../../color.png);
```

but not:

```
contents: url(/color.ong);
```

**EDIT:**
I'm a moron. Thank you guys for your help- it actually clicked something in my brain.

Comment: Are you sure that the path relative to the stylesheet is correct? I notice you have a leading `/`.

Comment: Do you miss there quotes 'xx' .... background-image: url('../../images/image.png');        ?

Comment: I got it to work by doing


content: url(../../../color2.png)

Why doesn't the root path method work? Like:

content: url(/folders/file.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your website file path is like this:

CSS

`www.YourWebsite.com/css/yourCss.css`

and your image is here:

`www.YourWebsite.com/images/yourImage.png`

Your relative path would be

`../images/yourImage.png`

The `../` goes back one folder then targets the `images/` folder.

**Also note that the images folder in your first example is `/images/` and in your relative path example you are using `/img/`**

Comment: The two paths are unrelated except the png file. The first is the image from some other website. The second is the relative path in my machine.

Comment: @8protons You are trying to connect a image that is on your machine? Are you using your machine as a server to host your wordpress site?

Comment: So I see the site is on godaddy, you will need to upload the image to godady then target the image from there, **you will not be able to target your local machine from your godaddy website**

Answer (score 1):

Please check again your ***right path to the file*** or try to Remove `/` from the **path to your file** and try again..  as follows

```
.my_class {
     content: url(img/color.png);
}
```

Here's **[when to to use forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path)**