# Route to api work wrong

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When i make GET request from http://localhost:5086/ it work great it send to **api/FileBrowser**, but when i try to make request from http://localhost:5086/Home/Index to api, to url added controller Home and request send to **/Home/api/FileBrowser**

Please help what i'm doing wrong?

ApiController with 2 methods

```
public FileBrowserModel Get()
    {
        var result = new FileBrowserModel();
        List<string> drives = new List<string>();
        foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            var path = drive.Name;
            FileManagerCounter fmCounter = new FileManagerCounter(path);
            result.CountTo10Mb += fmCounter.CountTo10Mb;
            result.Countfrom10To50Mb += fmCounter.Countfrom10To50Mb;
            result.CountFrom100Mb += fmCounter.CountFrom100Mb;
            drives.Add(path);
        }
        result.SubDirectories = new List<string>(drives);
        return result;
    }
    [CacheOutput(ServerTimeSpan = 150)]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public FileBrowserModel Get(string path)
    {
        var result = new FileBrowserModel();

        try
        {
            try
            {
                result.ParentPath  = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
            result.Files = new List<string>(files);
            result.CurrentPath = path;
            FileManagerCounter fmCounter = new FileManagerCounter(path);
            result.CountTo10Mb = fmCounter.CountTo10Mb;
            result.Countfrom10To50Mb = fmCounter.Countfrom10To50Mb;
            result.CountFrom100Mb = fmCounter.CountFrom100Mb;

            var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToList();
            result.SubDirectories = new List<string>(subDirectories);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

js File

```
angular.module("FileBrowserApp", [])
.controller("fileBrowserController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getFileBrowsing = function (path) {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        if (path != null) {
            $http({
                url: "api/FileBrowser?path=" + encodeURIComponent(path),
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.fileBrowserModel = data;
                $scope.isLoading = false;
            });
        } else {
            $http({
                url: "api/FileBrowser",
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.fileBrowserModel = data;
                $scope.isLoading = false;
            });
        }
    };
    $scope.getFileBrowsing();
});
```

Routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{path}",
            defaults: new { path = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that your Web API layer will always exist one layer above the root domain then you can change your urls in your ajax calls to be:

```
url: "/api/..."
```

This calls the api relative to the root domain regardless of how the site may be structured.

Comment: This is clean and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : War10ck's answer is the easy solution.

---

***The below is an alternate solution which builds the relative url properly***

The problem is, you hardcoded the url value to be "api/FileBrowser". So based on the current page, this value is going to change.If you are on Home page, It will be `Home/api/FileBrowser`.

What you should be doing is to build the correct relative url. Since you are using an asp.net mvc page, you may take advatage of the Url.Action helper method to build the correct relative url. You can generate the value of your application route in a razor view and pass that to your angular controller/data services and use that.

So in your razor view,

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};
    myApp.Urls = myApp.Urls || {};
    myApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';       
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularControllerForPage.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = angular.module("FileBrowserApp").value("appSettings", myApp);
</script>
```

and in your angular controllers, you can access this appSettings.

```
var app = angular.module("FileBrowserApp", []);
var ctrl = function (appSettings) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.baseUrl = appSettings.Urls.baseUrl;
    //build other urls using the base url now
    var fileBrowserUrl= vm.baseUrl + "api/FileBrowser";
    alert(fileBrowserUrl);
    //You can use this variable value for your http call now
    $http({
            url: fileBrowserUrl+ "?path=" + encodeURIComponent(path),
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.fileBrowserModel = data;
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        });

};
app.controller("fileBrowserController", ctrl)
```

You can and **should** access this in your data services and directives etc and use that to build the correct url.

You may also consider moving your http calls to a data service from your angular controller.

Comment: If the `api` directory is always one level above the root of the site would not a simple `/api/...` do the trick?

Comment: What if you want to make the call from `/Home/Customer/Edit/23` ?. The above solution will work irrespective of what level of deepness you are in

Comment: So will the `/api/...`. If `api` one directory up from the root it won't matter. `/api/` is relative to the site root not the directory root so as long as your api is one level up from root you can reference it in the previously described manner, regardless of how many directories deep your code is nested in.

Comment: What if you want to make the same call from `/Home/Customer/Edit/23` page ? Then with your approach the url will be `/Home/Customer/Edit/api/FileBrowser` which is wrong !

Comment: False. A forward slash `/api/...` is relative to the root directory, not the current directory. A `./api/...` slash is relative to the current directory same as simply writing `api/...` which indeed is wrong. See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path, for clarification.

Comment: We are talking about javascript. rite ? How does javascript know `/` is root ? I suggest you try it from a page i mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't know the root of your file structure but wil will know the root of your domain: `www.example.com <-- root`. In the question I linked to, _@Oded_ describes how this works. SO even uses this approach in linking their href tags. The questions button in the top nav looks like this: `<a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a>` where `/questions` is relative to the site root `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks ! Did not know that.

Comment: No worries, it's neat stuff. You've added an interesting approach as well that I've never seen before. +1 and happy coding :)