# webpack-dev-server historyApiFallback not working in case of multilevel routing

Tags: typescript, webpack-dev-server

I am using `historyApiFallback: true` to redirect all non-existing urls to index page. It is working fine for 1st level route, say localhost:8080/abc . But when I try localhost:8080/abc/xyz , I get error in browser console which says

> http://localhost:8080/abc/scripts/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Webpack config is

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:"./src/app.js",
    output:{
        path:path.join(__dirname,'public','scripts'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            loader:'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    devServer:{
        contentBase:path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        publicPath:'/scripts/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

Index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Folder structure is

```
-node_modules/
-public/
    -scripts/
    -index.html
-src/
    -app.js
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing forward slash in the script tag in html was causing the problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path) helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can refine the behaviour further using `rewrites`. From [the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback):

```
historyApiFallback: {
  rewrites: [
    { from: /^\/$/, to: '/views/landing.html' },
    { from: /^\/subpage/, to: '/views/subpage.html' },
    { from: /./, to: '/views/404.html' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have added -  rewrites: [
       { from: /^\/[a-z]*/, to: '/index.html' },
     ]

now index is getting served from localhost:8080/abc/xyz but bundle.js does not contain the compiled code written in app.js, instead it contains the html content.

Comment: Glad your devServer is working now. Sounds like you have a new question, that is going to be a different issue. I use [html-webpack-plugin](http://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to pack html content.

Comment: using rewrite we can have specific fallback but it didn't solved my problem. Later on I realised what was going wrong. It was just adding a forward slash at the start in script tag in html which worked fine with historyApiFallback: true.