# Django passing a variable through the path, causing path repetitions. how to get out of that loop?

Tags: django, django-urls

I know this is an armature question but here goes.

I have a url path as follows:
`path('projects/<s>', PL.projects),`

And I pass a string from the html template by putting it into an href tag like so `projects/some_string`. this works once but then the base url changes to `<ip>/projects/some_string`. so when I try to excite the path to pass a string in that domain then I get an error as the url is now `<ip>/projects/projects/some_string`.

How do I set it up so that I can pass as many strings as possible as many times as possible without having to clean my url in the browser everytime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has inbuilt url lookup features

```
path("some_random_url_link_1/", views.Link1View.as_view(), name="url_link_1"),
path("some_random_url_link_2/<int:some_id>/<slug:some_slug>/", views.Link2View.as_view(), name="url_link_2"),
```

in your template you can use it like this, and pass variables/parameters like this. FYI you don't need to use `{{variable}}` tag here

```
<a href="{% url 'url_link_1' %}" >Link 1</a>
<a href="{% url 'url_link_2' some_id=id1 some_slug=random_slug %}" >Link 2</a>
```

Comment: how do i fix this ```Reverse for 'projects_with_file' with keyword arguments '{'some_slug': 'templates copy'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects_with_file/(?P<some_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Comment: which version of django are you using? also please share your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use the `reverse()` function and the `url` template tag and your problems will be gone.

Those functions are built-in with Django and can handle all of that nasty URL stuff.

Reverse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/

Url Template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url