# The links are working fine in VS Code but when I open from folder, the links stop working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I made a website for our project in HTML and the HTML links are working fine in VSCode. However, when I open the HTML file for the main page in the folder itself (not from the live preview from VSCode), the links stop working and show this error:
[image]

This is a snippet of the codes that I'm using:

```
    <header id="top">  
    <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
        <source src="bg vid 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div style="padding: 10%;">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="logo" src="Logo Transparent.png"/>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Chingu K-Pop Merch</h1>   
    <nav style="text-align: center;">
        <a class="button" href="index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Main Page</a>
        <div class="products-dropdown">
            <button class="button" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-box"></i> Products</button>
            <div class ="products-content">
                <a href="All Products.html">All Products</a>
                <a href="/Boy Groups/Kpop_Boy_Group.html">All Boy Groups</a>
                <a href="/Girl Groups/Kpop_Girl_Group.html">All Girl Groups</a>
                <a href="/Soloists/SOLOISTS.html">All Solo Artists</a>
                <div style="height: 20px; background-color: white; color: #B6E5D8;">~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</div>
                <a href="/Boy Groups/svt/Seventeen_Kpop_Boy_Group.html">SEVENTEEN</a>
                <a href="/Boy Groups/bts/BTS_Kpop_Boy_Group.html">BTS</a>
                <a href="/Boy Groups/exo/exo.html">EXO</a>
                <div style="height: 20px; background-color: white;color: #B6E5D8;">~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</div>
                <a href="/Girl Groups/ITZY and BP/ITZY.html">ITZY</a>
                <a href="/Girl Groups/ITZY and BP/BLACKPINK.html">BLACKPINK</a>
                <a href="/Girl Groups/twice/twice.html">TWICE</a>
                <div style="height: 20px; background-color: white;color: #B6E5D8;">~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</div>
                <a href="/Soloists/IU.html">IU</a> 
                <a href="/Soloists/CHUNGHA.html">CHUNGHA</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="button" href="/About The Developers Page HTML/Developers_AboutUs.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i> About Us</a>
        <a class="button" href="/Contact Us Page HTML/Contact_Us.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you share your code that you are using to display the image in your html?

Comment: @StefanSpeterDev What do you mean?

Comment: try adding a . before your source, for example <img src="./Logo transparent.png"/>

Comment: @StefanSpeterDev that worked for the other links too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the leading `/` you have in your link's `href`

Suppose you have a folder structure like this

[image]

and you are having an anchor tag like this.

```
<a href="/pages/about.html">About Page</a>
```

Serving from VS Code (Live Server)

Index Page URL: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
When you click on the `/pages/about.html` link it gets navigated to http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/about.html

Opening using File System

Index Page URL: file:///C:/Users/navee/Desktop/sample-app/index.html
On clicking about us will get navigated to file:///C:/pages/about.html

The problem is that you are using `/`(absolute path). You can solve this by adding a relative path like `./` or `../`

Check this: [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613300/17447)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using the links to local files in your pc

Therefore, once you are running the html in the local server it stops working

Please share your code, so the problem can be identified, otherwise, your problem is not clear

Comment: Updated the post, sorry about that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).