# Django HttpResponseRedirect() function

Tags: django

Consider:

```
flag = 0
folder_id = 0
if FolderEntries.objects.filter(entry = entry_id).exists():
   print("=======================yes in folder")
   flag = 1
   folder_object = FolderEntries.objects.get(entry = entry_id)
   folder_entries_object = model_to_dict(folder_object)

   print("-------------------------", folder_entries_object)
   folder_id = folder_entries_object['folder']
else:
   flag = 0


if flag == 1:

   returnHttpResponseRedirect('folder/'+str(folder_id)+'/')
else:
   if request.session.get('HTTP_REFERER', None):
       HTTP_REFERER = request.session.get('HTTP_REFERER')
       del request.session['HTTP_REFERER']
       return HttpResponseRedirect(HTTP_REFERER)
   return HttpResponseRedirect('editentry/'+str(entry_id))
```

In this case, if flag = 1, this is redirecting me to two URLs. These are:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/form-entries/edit-entry/folder/174/

URL "*folder/174*" is the URL that I need. But I am getting an unwanted URL, "*admin/form-entries/edit-entry/*".
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/folder/174 - is this the url you wanted?

Comment: yes i want this url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a forward slash *(/)* in your `HttpResponseRedirect` at the beginning of the URL string:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/folder/'+str(folder_id)+'/')
```

The URL must start with a slash, otherwise it will be treated as a relative URL.