# Django HttpResponseRedirect isn't working correctly

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to redirect using the HttpResponseRedirect and, in a tutorial on YT, the teacher typed the url like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("challenge/" + month_list[month-1])
```

so the url "http://localhost:8000/challenge/1" changed to "http://localhost:8000/challenge/january".

When I try to do it my url change to "http://localhost:8000/challenge/challenge/january", repeating again the "challenge".

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseNotFound,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your views here.

months_challenges = {
    "january" : "desafio janeiro",
    "february" : "desafio february",
    "march" : "desafio march",
    "april" : "desafio april",
    "may" : "desafio may",
    "june" : "desafio june",
    "july" : "desafio july",
    "august" : "desafio august",
    "september" : "desafio september",
    "october" : "desafio october",
    "november" : "desafio november",
    "december" : "desafio december",
    
    }

def month_challenge_num(request,month):
    month_list = list(months_challenges.keys())
    if(month>len(month_list)):
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Não achamos")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("challenge/" + month_list[month-1])


def month_challenge(request,month):
    try:
        return HttpResponse(months_challenges[month])
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Não achamos str")
```

urls.py of the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:month>",views.month_challenge_num),
    path("<str:month>",views.month_challenge)
]
```

urls.py of the project

```
"""monthly_challenges URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("challenge/", include("challenges.urls"), name="challenges")
]
```

I think the error is happening because the include in the urls.py of the project, but I don't know. I want to keep using this include, but I want to use the redirect function to redirect to another page that isn't include in the "challenges area"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with an absolute path, so with a leading slash:

```
def month_challenge_num(request,month):
    month_list = list(months_challenges)
    if month > len(month_list):
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Não achamos")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/challenge/{month_list[month-1]}')
```

It is however more convenient to work with a named view:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'challenge'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:month>/', views.month_challenge_num),
    path('<str:month>/', views.month_challenge, name='month')
]
```

and redirect with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def month_challenge_num(request,month):
    month_list = list(months_challenges)
    if month > len(month_list):
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Não achamos")
    else:
        return redirect('challenge:month', month_list[month-1])
```